# Error in extracting DDL for functions in DB2

Tags: python, db2

I used the below statement to extract the ddl for particular function using python in DB2.

Function name = 'DEPTEMPLOYEES'

```
DDL = "select text from syscat.routines where routineschema = {}
and routinename = {} and routinetype = 'F'".format(user_schema,objs.upper()) 
cursor.execute(DDL)
```

But when I tried to execute this statement am getting an error.

```
ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: SQLNumResultCols failed: [IBM][CLI
Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0206N  "DEPTEMPLOYEES" is not valid in the
context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703\r SQLCODE=-206
```

Can someone please help me to solve this error

Comment: Show us more of the code. Are you sure that your parameters are formatted as string literals, including single quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this, adding single quotes around the strings?

```
DDL = "select text from syscat.routines where routineschema = '{}'
and routinename = '{}' and routinetype = 'F'".format(user_schema,objs.upper()) 

cursor.execute(DDL)
```

Based on the error it seems that your parameters was printed and the quotes were missing. This turned the parameter into a keyword, hence the error message.